# What does “it” refer to in this line from “The Mental Hospital Garden”?

Tags: meaning, poetry, william-carlos-williams

What is “it” in the following [lines](https://archive.org/details/desertmusicother0000will/page/38/mode/2up) from "The Mental Hospital Garden" by William Carlos Williams?

> It is a bounty
>       
>       
>        
> from last year’s nest.
>
> <sub>Williams, William Carlos. "The Garden" (aka "The Mental Hospital Garden"). *[The Desert Music and Other Poems](https://archive.org/details/desertmusicother0000will/mode/2up)*. New York: Random House, 1949, rept. 1954. pp. [37–42](https://archive.org/details/desertmusicother0000will/page/36/mode/2up). Accessed at archive.com 6 January 2023.</sub>

I have two weak theories: The birds born into last year's nest are mating this year and have inspired these lovers to do the same (it is a bounty for them because it feels like a "cure" for the moment). OR "it" is the profusion of young lovers. And the lovers are really birds?! But there is mention of "fingers" later in the poem.